# How to Set AlignSpan Style on current cursor paragraph?

Tags: android, android-edittext, paragraph, text-alignment, spannablestring

I know for set a style into spannable, we can use setSpan(Object classOfStyle, int start, int end, int flags).
I wanna set alignspan into a current paragraph. Current paragraph detected by current cursor position. It`s possible? May i can get start-position and end-position of paragraph?

**Edit :**

A paragraph is a group of sentences. One of paragraph will be ended by "Enter Character".

Comment: If you don't know what a paragraph is, then your requirements aren't clear and there's really no answer to your question. Try to find out what you want to know first before asking a question on SO.

Answer (score 2):

I've written a small helper class (optimized for speed) that will do exactly what you want. You pass a Spannable object which will be parsed to find all paragraphs:

```
public class Layout {
    private static final Pattern LINEBREAK_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\r\\n|\\r|\\n");

    private int mNrOfLines = 0;
    private ArrayList<Selection> mSelection = new ArrayList<Selection>();

    public Layout(Spannable spannable) {
        String s = spannable.toString();

        // remove the trailing line feeds
        int len = s.length();
        char c = len > 0 ? s.charAt(len - 1) : '-';
        while (len > 0 && (c == '\n' || c == '\r')) {
            len--;
            c = s.charAt(len - 1);
        }

        // now find the line breaks and the according lines / paragraphs
        mNrOfLines = 1;
        Matcher m = LINEBREAK_PATTERN.matcher(s.substring(0, len));
        int groupStart = 0; 
        while (m.find()) {
            mSelection.add( new Selection(groupStart, m.end()) );
            groupStart = m.end();
            mNrOfLines++;
        }
        if (groupStart < len) {
            mSelection.add( new Selection(groupStart, len) );
        }
    }

    public List<Selection> getParagraphs() {
        return mSelection;
    }

    public int getLineForOffset(int offset) {
        int lineNr = 0;
        while(lineNr < mNrOfLines && offset >= mSelection.get(lineNr).end()) {
            lineNr++;
        }
        return Math.min(Math.max(0, lineNr), mSelection.size() - 1);
    }

    public int getLineStart(int line) {
        return mNrOfLines == 0 || line < 0 ? 0 :
               line<mNrOfLines ? mSelection.get(line).start() :
               mSelection.get(mNrOfLines-1).end()-1;
    }

    public int getLineEnd(int line) {
        return mNrOfLines == 0 || line < 0 ? 0 :
               line<mNrOfLines ? mSelection.get(line).end() :
               mSelection.get(mNrOfLines-1).end()-1;
    }
}
```

The three methods getLineForOffset, getLineStart and getLineEnd can be used to find the paragraphs for the current [Selection](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Selection.html). The [Selection](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Selection.html) can be either the current cursor position (which is basically a [Selection](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Selection.html) with start==end) or the selected text. The following code will return the selected paragraphs for the current selection:

```
Selection getParagraphs(EditText editor) {    
    Layout layout = new Layout( editor.getEditableText() );

    int selStart = editor.getSelectionStart();
    int selEnd = editor.getSelectionEnd();

    int firstLine = layout.getLineForOffset(selStart);
    int end = selStart == selEnd ? selEnd : selEnd - 1; 
    int lastLine = layout.getLineForOffset(end);

    return new Selection(layout.getLineStart(firstLine), layout.getLineEnd(lastLine));
}
```

If e.g. your text is:

> line 1
>   l[ine 2
>   line ]3
>   line 4

with everything between the [] selected, getParagraphs() would return the second and third line (it basically expands the selected text to include all (even partially) selected paragraphs.

Comment: Thank you.. I wanna ask again, but sorry out of thread topic. I see your k-mail app. How can you create font formating maybe only for standart formating  bold, italic and underline. I see on Wordpress Android source code, but its a lot of bug when formating font.

Comment: That's not a question I can answer on SO. My rich text editor was a lot of work, the above code is just a tiny piece to deal with paragraph formatting. You can check out this for a very simple rich text editor: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-richedit

Comment: If you think my code answers your question, don't hesitate to mark is as correct ;-).

Answer (score 0):

I Write some method for get first position of paragraph and last position of paragraph.
I don`t know, which one is better performance. Please correct me if its wrong.

```
    public static int getFirstPositionOfParagraph(String paragraph, int cursorPosition) {
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(paragraph);
        List pos = new ArrayList();
        for (String breaker : LINE_BREAK){
          pos.add(buffer.lastIndexOf(breaker, cursorPosition));
        }
        int firstPosition = Collections.max(pos);
        return firstPosition
```

```
      public static int getLastPositionOfParagraph(String paragraph, int cursorPosition) {
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(paragraph);
        List pos = new ArrayList();
        for (String breaker : LINE_BREAK){
          int breakerPos = buffer.indexOf(breaker, cursorPosition);
          if (breakerPos > 0)
            pos.add(breakerPos);
        }
        return pos.size() > 0 ? Collections.min(pos) + 1 : paragraph.length();
      }
```